# redux-persist/createPersistoid: error serializing state TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: react-native, redux, google-cloud-firestore, redux-persist

I am trying to integrate redux-persist to my react-native project. The aim is to persist the redux store's data between application re-launch so that user does not need to log in each time they launch the app. Also, I want to store the previously viewed data on the local storage to avoid re-querying all the data each time app is re-launched.

I added the redux persist support as per the code below:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
//import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createTransform } from 'redux-persist';
import JSOG from 'jsog';

export const JSOGTransform = createTransform(
    (inboundState, key) => JSOG.encode(inboundState),
    (outboundState, key) => JSOG.decode(outboundState),
)

const persistConfig = {
    // Root
    key: 'root',
    // Storage Method (React Native)
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    //transforms: [JSOGTransform]
    // Whitelist (Save Specific Reducers)
    // whitelist: [
    //   'authReducer',
    // ],
    // // Blacklist (Don't Save Specific Reducers)
    // blacklist: [
    //   'counterReducer',
    // ],
};

// Middleware: Redux Persist Persisted Reducer
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

// Redux: Store
const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
);

// Middleware: Redux Persist Persister
let persistor = persistStore(store);
// Exports
export {
  store,
  persistor,
};
```

If I don't add jsog and use the `transforms: [JSOGTransform]` line in the persistConfig I get this error:

> redux-persist/createPersistoid: error serializing state TypeError:
>   Converting circular structure to JSON

If I uncomment the 'transforms' line in the persistConfig (as per the suggestion here: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/735), then I get this error:

> Exception in HostObject::set: < unknown >

I am just persisting the returned "user" object from the **firestore** database in my redux-store. Without the redux-persist, there has been no problem, but with the persist added I am having this issue.

What type of circular problem would exist in the user object returned after successful login to firestore (using password/email auth.)?

Why would JSOG not work as suggested in the link above? Any alternatives to how I can solve this problem?

P.S. Not only the user returned from firestore is causing these errors, but any data returned from firestore seems to fail to persist.

I appreciate any helps!
Cheers...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I solved the problem. Instead of JSOG I installed [flatted](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted) and used in for my redux-persist transform.

Working transform and persistConfig looks like this:

```
export const transformCircular = createTransform(
    (inboundState, key) => Flatted.stringify(inboundState),
    (outboundState, key) => Flatted.parse(outboundState),
)

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
    transforms: [transformCircular]
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this,  I ended up using JSOG to fix this as for some reason Flatted was causing lot of firestore related build errors in my iOS build. Github issue reference below https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/735

Answer (score 0):

Some developer have this problem because of the socket set in Redax, Otherwise, you can use this way as well

```
// SetTransform.js

import { createTransform } from 'redux-persist';
 
const SetTransform = createTransform(
  // transform state on its way to being serialized and persisted.
  (inboundState, key) => {
    // convert mySet to an Array.
    return { ...inboundState, mySet: [...inboundState.mySet] };
  },
  // transform state being rehydrated
  (outboundState, key) => {
    // convert mySet back to a Set.
    return { ...outboundState, mySet: new Set(outboundState.mySet) };
  },
  // define which reducers this transform gets called for.
  { whitelist: ['someReducer'] }
);
 
export default SetTransform;
```

and

```
// PersistReducers 

import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { SetTransform } from './transforms';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  transforms: [SetTransform]
};
```